# Замыкание и функциональные выражения

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
    function test(){
        var x = 1;
      console.log('s');
      return function(){
      return x++;
      };
    }

var alpha = test();
```

Почему в alpha попадает только

```
function (){
  return x++;
  }
```

Comment: Потому что любая функция при вызове возвращает то, что сказано в операторе `return`. Вы ожидали чего-то другого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что переменной `alpha` присваивается *значение, возвращаемое функцией `test`* - и этим значением является анонимная функция `function () { return x++; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос, я полагаю потому что `alpha` присваивается функция которую возвращает `test()` перед этим объявив один раз `x` и логнув `s`.